# Returning handler.ResponseBuilder from promise.then() method

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

In one of the intent handler for my Alexa skill I have to return response once my promise is resolved.

Code looks like this :

```
var rcvPromise = receiveMsgQ();    
rcvPromise.then(function(speechText) { 
   console.log('rcv Promise resolved with ',speechText);    
   return handlerInput.responseBuilder
       .speak(speechText) 
       .withSimpleCard('skill_name', speechText) 
       .withShouldEndSession(false)
       .getResponse();        
   });
```

Skill returns with ERROR message with no additional details about error.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

PS: I need to use promise as `receiveMsgQ()` is asynchronous function call.

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: what is the error in nodejs logs

Comment: I could see just one line in a log : "Session ended with reason: ERROR"

Answer (score 5):

The error you're seeing is because NodeJS and the Alexa SDK are  asynchronous.  As you can read from the [Alexa SDK code](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/blob/2.0.x/ask-sdk-core/lib/skill/Skill.ts#L66), it invokes your request handlers and expects a Promise back.  In your example, as your code does not return anything explicitly after calling `rcvPromise.then`, an empty response is sent back, and the SDK sends an empty response to Alexa, causing the error.  When your `then()` function will be executed, the Alexa response has already been sent and your `handlerInput.responseBuilder` result is ignored.

To solve this problem, you have two solutions:

a/ you can insert a `return` statement before  `rcvPromise.then`, such as

```
return rcvPromise.then(function(speechText) {
   console.log('rcv Promise resolved with ',speechText);
     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
       .speak(speechText) 
       .withSimpleCard('skill_name', speechText) 
       .withShouldEndSession(false)
       .getResponse();
 });
```

This way, your handler will return a Promise to the SDK and the SDK will use the result of the promise to build the response to send to Alexa.

b/ If you are using NodeJS 8, you can use the new `await`/`async` syntax.  Under the hood, it is the same as the above solution, but it will make the code easier to read.

```
var speechText = await receiveMsgQ();
console.log('rcv Promise resolved with ',speechText);
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
       .speak(speechText) 
       .withSimpleCard('skill_name', speechText) 
       .withShouldEndSession(false)
       .getResponse();
```

Note that your entire handler function must be marked as `async` for this to work.  Read more about `async` and `await` at https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/