# How to trouble shoot "NaN" error when the call to a function and assigning to let is the only visible issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, nan, alexa-skills-kit

I'm testing an Alexa skill locally and getting an error that just says NaN. I have figured out that line `let recipe = getRecipe()` is the problem through `console.log()` statements. It doesn't appear to be in the the `getRecipe()` function itself because a `console.log()` statement at the very beginning of the try block in that function does not run, but the one at the beginning of the catch does. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Handler:

```js
    handle(handlerInput){
    const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    switch (attributes.previousIntent){
      case "FoodIntent":
        
        if(request.intent.slots.answer.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name === 'yes'){
          let randomFood = Helpers.suggestFood(handlerInput);         
          let queryFood = randomFood.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); event
          attributes.currentSuggestedFood = queryFood;           
          const speechText = 'Great! In the future I will be able to look up the ingredients for you.'
          console.log('before call getRecipe()')
          let recipe = getRecipe(handlerInput)
          console.log('After call getRecipe()')

          return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText + " "+ recipe)
          .reprompt(speechText)
          .withShouldEndSession(true)
          .withSimpleCard('Cheer Up - YesNo', speechText)
          .getResponse();
          
        } else {
          let randomFood = Helpers.suggestFood(handlerInput);
          let speechText = ResponseToUsersNo[Math.floor(Math.random() * ResponseToUsersNo.length)]+ 
                            FoodPrefixes[Math.floor(Math.random() * FoodPrefixes.length)] + 
                            randomFood + FoodSuffixes[Math.floor(Math.random() * FoodSuffixes.length)];
          let repromptText = 'Did the last suggestion work for you?'
          handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(attributes);
          
          if (attributes.FoodsAlreadySuggested.length >= 10) {
            speechText = 'I feel like you don\'t actually want anything. So I\'m leaving for now, talk to you later.'
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .withShouldEndSession(true)
            .withSimpleCard('Cheer Up - YesNo', speechText)
            .getResponse();
          }
          
          return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(repromptText)
          .withSimpleCard('Cheer Up - YesNo', speechText)
          .getResponse();
        }
      case "HobbyIntent":
         
        if(request.intent.slots
```

And the getRecipe() function:

```
 async function getRecipe(handlerInput) {

  try{
    console.log('before attributes')
    const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    console.log('attributes: '+ attributes)
    console.log('before url')
    const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${attributes.currentSuggestedFood}&app_id=${FOOD_APP_ID}&app_key=${FOOD_APP_KEY}`;  //&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free   this was on the end of the uri
    console.log(url)
    console.log('after url')
    request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
      // let json = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      console.log('body:', body); // Print the body

      //const theRecipe = await body;
      const payload = JSON.parse(body)
      console.log("The ingredients for "+ payload.q + " is: ")
      console.log(payload.hits[0].recipe.ingredientLines)

      return (payload.hits[0].recipe.ingredientLines);

  });
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log('before error statement in catch')
    console.error('There was an error: ', + err)
  }  
};
```

Here is my output:

```
    before call getRecipe()
before attributes
attributes: [object Object]
before url
https://api.edamam.com/search?q=rellenos-de-papa&app_id=b4dbea92&app_key=8d916c99b930b77c8cbb4615f0800df7
after url
before error statement in catch
There was an error:  NaN
After call getRecipe()
{ version: '1.0',
  response:
   { outputSpeech:
      { type: 'SSML',
        ssml: '<speak>Great! In the future I will be able to look up the ingredients for you. The ingredients are [object Promise]</speak>' },
     reprompt: { outputSpeech: [Object] },
     shouldEndSession: true,
     card:
      { type: 'Simple',
        title: 'Cheer Up - YesNo',
        content: 'Great! In the future I will be able to look up the 
    ingredients for you.' } },
     userAgent: 'ask-node/2.3.0 Node/v8.12.0',
     sessionAttributes:
   { foodType: 'PuertoRican',
     FoodsAlreadySuggested: [ 'Platanos Maduros', 'Rellenos de Papa' ],
     previousIntent: 'FoodIntent',
     state: '_YES_NO',
     currentSuggestedFood: 'rellenos-de-papa' } }
```

UPDATE:

@Shilly. So I'm still confused... An aside, I had to edit your function a bit to make the code inside the catch reachable... but anyway I think what I did still retains the core logic you were trying to impart.
My problem is that I get an error when I parse that says `unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. I think this usually means I don't need to parse it because it's already a valid js object. Cool. So I remove the parse, but then I get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined.`, referring of course to my `return payload.hits[0].recipe.ingredientLines`. Can't seem to wrap my head around why. Thanks a bunch for your help.

```
function getRecipe(handlerInput) {
  const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${attributes.currentSuggestedFood}&app_id=${FOOD_APP_ID}&app_key=${FOOD_APP_KEY}`;  //&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free   this was on the end of the uri
  return get( url, ( response, body ) => {
    const payload = JSON.parse(body)
    console.log(payload)
    return payload.hits[0].recipe.ingredientLines;
  }).catch( error => {
    console.error( `failed GET request for: ${ url }` );
    console.error( error );
  }); 
};
```

Also here is the beginning of the body in the response, which doesn't look parsed to me... `body: '{\n  "q" : "tostones",\n  "from" : 0,\n  "to" : 10,\n  "params" : {\n`

Comment: In your output, `before url` never logs. So we need to see the `handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Many thanks to @Shilly for guiding me in the proper direction. My understanding of async and await was wrong. These sources were helpful:

[Returning handler.ResponseBuilder from promise.then() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780950/returning-handler-responsebuilder-from-promise-then-method)

https://medium.com/@tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c

Here is my updated code:

The async handler relies on a function that I created to use Promises with @Shilly's help. It's probably not the most concise way, but it works!

Handler:

```
async handle(handlerInput){ 
    const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    switch (attributes.previousIntent){
      case "FoodIntent":

        if(request.intent.slots.answer.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name === 'yes'){
          let randomFood = Helpers.suggestFood(handlerInput);         
          let queryFood = randomFood.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); 
          attributes.currentSuggestedFood = queryFood;           
          const speechText = 'Great! Here are the ingredients!'
          let recipe = await getRecipe(handlerInput)
            let recipeIngredients = recipe.hits[0].recipe.ingredientLines;
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText+ 'The ingredients are '+ recipeIngredients)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withShouldEndSession(true)
            .withSimpleCard('Cheer Up - YesIntentFood', recipeIngredients)
            .getResponse();
```

function:

```
async function getRecipe(handlerInput) {
  const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${attributes.currentSuggestedFood}&app_id=${FOOD_APP_ID}&app_key=${FOOD_APP_KEY}`;
  console.log(url)
  return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
          resolve(JSON.parse(body))
      }
  });
})
};
```

Output:

```
https://api.edamam.com/search?q=pernil&app_id=b4dbea92&app_key=8d916c99b930b77c8cbb4615f0800df7
{ version: '1.0',
  response:
   { outputSpeech:
      { type: 'SSML',
        ssml: '<speak>Great! In the future I will be able to look up the ingredients for you.The ingredients are 2 1/2 pounds pork shoulder, boston butt, pernil,2 garlic cloves,1 small onion,1 bunch cilantro,1 jalapeño,1 cup orange juice,1 cup pineapple juice,1 lemon,Handfuls salt,Pepper to taste,Ground cumin</speak>' },
     reprompt: { outputSpeech: [Object] },
     shouldEndSession: true,
     card:
      { type: 'Simple',
        title: 'Cheer Up - YesIntentFood',
        content: [Array] } },
  userAgent: 'ask-node/2.3.0 Node/v8.12.0',
  sessionAttributes:
   { foodType: 'PuertoRican',
     FoodsAlreadySuggested: [ 'Platanos Maduros', 'Pernil' ],
     previousIntent: 'FoodIntent',
     state: '_YES_NO',
     currentSuggestedFood: 'pernil' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

`const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes()` throws an error NaN for reasons still unknown.

The catch() handler catches this error and logs it.
But since the function is async, and you don't resolve the promise inside the catch clause, you get this `[object Promise]` stringified version of that promise instead of the actual ingredient list.

Edit:

Have you considered using util.promisify() so you don't have to mix callbacks and promises?

```
const { promisify } = require( 'util' );
const request = require( 'request' );
const get = promisify( request.get );

function getRecipe(handlerInput) {
  const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${attributes.currentSuggestedFood}&app_id=${FOOD_APP_ID}&app_key=${FOOD_APP_KEY}`;  //&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free   this was on the end of the uri
  return get( url, ( response, body ) => {
    const payload = JSON.parse(body)
    return payload.hits[0].recipe.ingredientLines;
  }).catch( error ) {
    console.error( `failed GET request for: ${ url }` );
    console.error( error );
  }); 
};
```

Same can be written with async/await style, but I'm not fluent enough in it to get it 100% correct without being able to test the code myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Shilly I updated the code. I have before url printing, and I do get an object Promise back from the call to attributes. Still a little confused, but you've put me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: Strange, though @Shilly, when I print the url it has my desired value as the query string, gathered from the session attributes.

Comment: I'll have a look at the updated code and updated error log.

Comment: There's still an issue with the promise not resolving correctly due to the mixing of callbacks and promsies and async/await. Since you use node.js, have you tried `promisify()` ? That would allow you to just return or await the request.get() call. I'll add the code in an edit.

Comment: Updated. The code shown does expect the use of a promise chain then to get the recipe, so `let recipe = getRecipe(handlerInput).then( ... );`, But it can be written as async/await if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Shilly! I'll check it out and respond back. I'm fairly new so it might take me a little bit.

Comment: Hey @Shilly, I added an update regarding some confusion. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @dillon.harless Have you ran the JSON string through jsonlint.com to verify that you actually have a valid JSON body to parse? Have you logged response.body to see that it's the correct JSON? Have you checked that payload is the structure you expect it to be? So an object contain an array as the property hits and so on. Maybe all the previous code actually worked, but it's the data that's wrong. I'm logging off for the day, so I'll have a look tomorrow if you haven't managed to find the issue. Good luck! :)

Comment: thanks for the effort. If I figure it out before then I will let you know. Either way, thanks!

Comment: Sorry to uncheck your answer, but I figured it out! In the event someone comes here looking for a solution I think it would be wise to put the green next to what I eventually did.